# What's the difference between REGEXP_SUBSTR and REGEXP_EXTRACT?

Tags: db2, regex, db2-midrange

What's the difference between REGEXP_SUBSTR and REGEXP_EXTRACT?

As far as I can tell, they seem to do the same thing. Is there some difference in side-effects, or how they perform for certain inputs? How do I know which to choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both the same function but one was specifically designed for IBM PureData System for Analytics, which is the [regexp_extract()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/r_sqlext_regexp_extract.html) function. The other function [REGEXP_SUBSTR()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzscaregexp_substr.htm) is for DB2 only and doesn't exist on PureData System for Analytics.

Use the one that correlates to whichever system you're working in (seems like DB2).